# How do Events affect uncontacted empires?

Tags: endless-space

Events in *Endless Space* have three options: Selfish, Helpful and Hostile. The rewards/consequences of these can affect one's own star systems, fleets, etc., or those of enemies, or even those of all empires in the galaxy.

How does this work for empires I haven't met yet? If I choose something that helps/hinders "all empires", does this affect **everyone**, regardless of whether we've met or not?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will effect everyone. Events that state 'All factions/empires' will impact undiscovered players. Note that this is easier to test in multiplayer matches.